# Why is the if statement not being called?

Tags: bash

I am a beginner in Bash scripting looking for some help with my project. In my script (code below) I am looking to allow the users to enter two numbers: a starting number and an ending number.

The even numbers within this range should only be printed out, which I've managed to do.

I'm now looking for certain numbers if they meet the requirement of being divisible by seven for example to print out a word next to it i.e. 14: Chocolate.

Ive tried implementing the following if statement however It doesn't seem to work.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter first number:"
read firstnum
echo "Enter second number:"    
read secondnum

for ((firstnum = 0; counter <= secondnum; counter +=2)); do
 echo "$counter"
done

if (( $counter % 7 )); then
 echo "$counter: Drink"
fi
```

I hope your able to help with this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the `if` be inside the loop?

Comment: Pretty sure that `firstnum = 0` should be `counter = firstnum`. You also don't need the `$` in your `if` statement, and I'm guessing the `if` should be inside the loop?

Comment: Using `read` like that will cause issues as it captures newlines which you really don't want in your "numbers". You also need `counter % 7 == 0` in your `if`, as `%` is a binary operation, not a binary predicate.

Answer (score 0):

some ideas:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter first number: "
read firstnum
echo -n "Enter second number: "    
read secondnum
echo


# ideally here, verify that :
# the values are numeric
# firstnum < secondnum

for (( counter = firstnum; counter <= secondnum; counter += 1 )); do    # counter += 2 is valid also
    if (( counter % 2 )); then
        echo "$counter Drink"
    else
        echo "$counter: even"
    fi
done
```